# ag-grid refresh rowStyle to default after redux action

Tags: ag-grid

I have a react-redux app, where in my ag-grid I use getRowStyle to set rows based on a certain field value. For instance, if a row's edited I set a field called isDirty to true and pass this to redux, which updates state and then via props I get this back and page re-renders and makes use of getRowStyle to set this row to a diff style, like below -

```
_getRowStyle = params => {
if (params.node.data.isDirty) {
  return {'fontWeight': 'bold'};
}
```

};

But, once this is persisted somewhere (thru' my redux-action), I update the state's isDirty to false. Again, this is received via props, and re-renders, but now in _getRowStyle() the "if" is no longer true, so it doesn't default back to the original value, so the row remains in "bold" style. If I force a gridApi.redrawRows(), it renders correctly, but I want to see if I can somehow avoid this heavy operation. All that is needed a refresh, but refreshCells() doesn't give me what I'm after.

Any assistance is deeply appreciated!

Comment: have you tried  resetting to the normal font in else block?

Comment: We are using the dark theme that ships in ag-grid, so not sure what the normal style would be in this case.